# Change onclick event in highchart ,pie chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

i'm using highchart chart API for a system.The pie chart of HighChart library ,which i'm using ,there is a mouse click event on the pie , on click event the pie is moving a little bit away.What i need to do is ,bind the event not to the click event , to mouse over event.and on mouse out the pie should be come to first place again.can anyone help me , thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use "slicedOffset: 0" (inside the "pie" object) to prevent the slice from moving.

Then, you can use the click event. Take a look at the API:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.events.click

From the event handler you can get the string with "this.name"
or even get some kind of identifier with "this.options.somevariable"

"somevariable" means whatever variable name you create in the series data. For example in my case I name the identifier as simply "id":

```
{
   name: "Slice 6",
   id: 6,
   events: { 
      click: function()
      {
         alert(
            'The name is ' + this.name +
            ' and the identifier is ' + this.options.id
         );
      }
   }
}
```